# Convert Excel to Google Sheets after uploading without resharing - e.g. keeping the same URL

Tags: excel, google-sheets

We have several files which have been uploaded to Google Drive as .XLS files (e.g. without being converted). These have then been shared out amongst our company for updates to be entered by multiple people.

I now have the job of reporting on those updates but I can't use IMPORTRANGE due to the fact that it is an Excel file still (I get the indefinite 'adding permissions' error).

I already know how to automatically convert to google sheets and how to create a 'new' google sheet (File-->Save as Google Sheet) but I can't seem to find a way to convert the existing .XLS file to a google sheet in situ - e.g. without having to re-share and cause company-wide confusion over which file to update.

Does anybody know of a way to convert the .XLS file to Google Sheets but keep the same URL (e.g. the already shared one)?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: About `a way to convert the .XLS file to Google Sheets but keep the same URL`, when XLS is converted to Google Spreadsheet, the file ID is changed. By this, I'm worried that `but keep the same URL` of your expected result cannot be achieved.

Comment: @Tanaike That is my worry - I think I will have to convert and then strip out the .XLS version of data and just leave a link to the new, google sheets, version of the file - that will direct people accordingly and not give them the option to update the *wrong* sheet. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

As Tanaike [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75887851/convert-excel-to-google-sheets-after-uploading-without-resharing-e-g-keeping#comment133856311_75887851), there's no way to convert the file from Excel to Sheets and keep the same URL.

However, there is a potential workaround where you can keep having your users write to the same `.xlsx` files, convert their data to separate Sheets files, and then import your data from these Sheet files with `IMPORTRANGE`.

The way the API works is that when you "convert" an Excel file to Sheets, a blank Google Sheets "container" is created with [`files.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), then this container is filled with the converted Excel data. So, even after the file has been created you can keep "refilling" this container with new data from Excel files. The [`files.update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) method allows you to do this. You can pretty much update a Sheets file with an entire Excel file as much as you need.

So my suggestion looks kind of like this:

- Users keep writing their data to the original Excel files.
- Create a blank Sheet for each Excel file.
- Use `files.update` periodically to update the Sheets with the Excel data.
- Use `IMPORTRANGE` from your report file to read the Sheets instead.

Note that you will have to first download the file and get it as a blob to then pass it to `files.update`. Another caveat is that apparently this API rewriting does not trigger the imports as user editing usually does, so the data gets cached for longer and doesn't get updated as often as it should, i.e., the data will be delayed.

All in all, depending on your use case it may be too much effort to make this work and it could make more sense to just migrate everything to Sheets, so it's up to you if you want to do it this way, but at least it's here for future reference.

##### References

- [Uploading file data](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads)
- [Files:update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)
- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads)